# Tableview not scrolling smooth with static data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios9

I am using custom `cell` and `headerView` with static images and `footerView` but not scrolling as smoothly as it should scroll, it is getting stuck in middle and then scrolls........

**Header**

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

UIView *headerview = [[UIView alloc]init];

if (section == 2) {
    headerview.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 30, tableView.frame.size.width, 117);
    Button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 18, headerview.frame.size.width, 100)];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 17)];
    label.text = @"Siddharth and hiren Like this";
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [headerview addSubview:label];


}
else
{

    headerview.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 100);
    Button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:headerview.frame];


}



// sheap top left and top right


UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:headerview.bounds
                                 byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                       cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(7.0, 7.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
headerview.frame = headerview.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
headerview.layer.mask = maskLayer;


// shape for button bottom



headerview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0, headerview.frame.size.width, 1);
bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:217/255.0f green:217/255.0f blue:217/255.0f alpha:1].CGColor;
bottomBorder.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
bottomBorder.shadowOpacity = 0.9f;
bottomBorder.shadowRadius = 0.3f;
[headerview.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];


headerview.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;


// Button Imageview

UIImageView *buttonimg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:Button.bounds];
buttonimg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_SecImgArray objectAtIndex:section]];
buttonimg.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
[Button addSubview:buttonimg];


// imageview overlay

UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:Button.bounds];
overlay.alpha = 0.3;
overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
overlay.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
[buttonimg addSubview:overlay];

[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(Expand: and:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
Button.tag = section;


if ([[AllNewsdic objectForKey:@"posts"] count] == 0) {
    [Button setTitle:[[[DownloadData objectForKey:@"posts"]objectAtIndex:section]objectForKey:@"title"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    [Button setTitle:[[[AllNewsdic objectForKey:@"posts"]objectAtIndex:section]objectForKey:@"title"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

[Button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
Button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
Button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom;
Button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
Button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
Button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
Button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:12];
Button.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
Button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4;
Button.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0f;
Button.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
Button.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
Button.layer.shouldRasterize   = YES;
[headerview addSubview:Button];
  return headerview;}
```

**Footer**

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
              UIView *fotter = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -10, tableView.frame.size.width, 30)];
fotter.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

 // corner redius

UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:fotter.bounds
                                 byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerBottomRight)
                                       cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(7.0, 7.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
fotter.frame = fotter.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
    // maskLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:217/255.0f green:217/255.0f blue:217/255.0f alpha:1].CGColor;
fotter.layer.mask = maskLayer;

 // Bottom layer

CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 32, fotter.frame.size.width, 2);
bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
[fotter.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];

// top Layer
CALayer *topLayer = [CALayer layer];
topLayer.frame = CGRectMake(13, 0, fotter.frame.size.width - 26, 0.7);
topLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:197/255.0f green:187/255.0f blue:188/255.0f alpha:1].CGColor;
topLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.6f;
topLayer.shadowRadius = 0.5f;
[fotter.layer addSublayer:topLayer];

// Like bUtton

likebutton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -3, fotter.frame.size.width/2, fotter.frame.size.height + 3)];
likebutton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
likebutton.titleLabel.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:197/255.0f green:187/255.0f blue:188/255.0f alpha:1];
[likebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(like:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[likebutton setTitle:@"1 likes" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
likebutton.tag = section;
like = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40 ,8, 15, 15)];
like.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SimpleLike.png"];
[likebutton addSubview:like];
[likebutton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[fotter addSubview:likebutton];

// Follow Button
NSLog(@"%f",fotter.frame.size.width/2 + 1);
follow = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(fotter.frame.size.width/2  , -3, fotter.frame.size.width/2, fotter.frame.size.height + 3)];
follow.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
follow.titleLabel.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:197/255.0f green:187/255.0f blue:188/255.0f alpha:1];
[follow setTitle:@"Follow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
followimage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35 ,8, 17, 17)];
followimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Follow.png"];
[follow addSubview:followimage];
[follow setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
follow.tag = section;
[follow addTarget:self action:@selector(Follow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[fotter addSubview:follow];

return fotter;}
```

**Cell**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
AllNewsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AllNews"];

cell.one.text = [one objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
cell.two.text = [two objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
cell.three.text = [three objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
[cell.three sizeToFit];
return cell;}
```

**how to set tableview scroll smooth and effective**
**how to set interface properties**
**tableview data is static**

Comment: i think your scrolling is not smoothly scroll because of the CAShapeLayer class. You have to create only one time every time this class load and stuck the UI

Comment: if i remove all data then also scroll not working smooth

Comment: Remove all CALayer and CAShapeLayer code then check!

Comment: do you have a lot of sections? maybe you want to create the header view in viewDidLoad and cache it, then use it in your tableview's  header or footer method.

Comment: ok but if i will remove all section  and  footer  then after its not work

Comment: any one changes need to  interface builder

Comment: try to comment out the sizeToFit and try again? or do you add any code to listen for the scrolling event?

Comment: yes i added scrollview delegate

Comment: maybe you can show your code for those delegate methods, if you do heavy operation there, it definitely would affect the scrolling

Comment: you can just test it first, comment out the line you set the scrollview delegate and see if it scrolls smoother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reusable **UITableViewCell** inside function **viewForHeaderInSection** and inside **viewForFooterInSection**
Do not create the new UIView and buttons for each function call.

Comment: how to use cell  inside the view for header ?

Comment: -(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
       
    MyTableViewCell *headerView = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"some cell"];
....
do something with content     
...
    return headerView;
}

Comment: You need to put drawings and creation of Buttons to initialization section UITableViewCell parent class

Answer (score 0):

Your table view scrolling is not smooth because the views inside `viewForHeaderInSection` and `viewForFooterInSection` methods are allocated multiple times. Why ? Because whenever you scroll up and down, both the methods are called as and when required.

Check whether header view is already allocated. If it is `nil`, then and then allocate it and return it. Otherwise, just return it. Same way in case of footer view.

Add comment in case of any doubt..