# TableView lags when Scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to implement a table like facebook or twitter timeline. but when I scroll the `UITableView`, it's very slow and lagging. How can I fix this problem ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ViewControllerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"htrcell"];
    if (cell==nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSDictionary *dataArray = [self.threndsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[dataArray objectForKey:@"pic_timeline"]];

    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    cell.upload_image.image =[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];

    NSURL *urlimage = [NSURL URLWithString:[dataArray objectForKey:@"pic_user"]];
    NSData *Dataimage = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlimage];
    cell.uploder_image.image =[UIImage imageWithData:Dataimage];
    cell.uploder_image.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.uploder_image.layer.cornerRadius = cell.uploder_image.frame.size.height /2;
    cell.uploder_image.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    cell.uploder_image.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    cell.uploder_name.text=[dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"nama_user"];

    cell.like_counter.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"likes"]];

    cell.commenter_name.text=[dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"status_timeline"];

    cell.comments.text=[dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"tgl_timeline"];


    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return  cell;
}
```

Comment: apply image circle code in cell class and fetch image using afnetworking

Comment: chek here :-  http://stackoverflow.com/q/34765218/5461400

Comment: You need to put image downloading in a background queue.

Comment: You are downloading images in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This causes lagging. You should use some cache library to prevent downloading image. I suggest https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is [SDWebImageView](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) 
Download and Use Like Bellow :

**Import 2 files in your .h**

> ```
> #import "SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h"
> #import "UIImageView+UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage.h"
> ```

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ViewControllerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"htrcell"];
    if (cell==nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSDictionary *dataArray = [self.threndsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[dataArray objectForKey:@"pic_timeline"]];

    [cell.upload_image setImageWithURL:[dataArray objectForKey:@"pic_timeline"] placeholderImage:nil usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    cell.uploder_image.clipsToBounds = YES;
    cell.uploder_image.layer.cornerRadius =       cell.uploder_image.frame.size.height /2;
    cell.uploder_image.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    cell.uploder_image.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;


    cell.uploder_name.text=[dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"nama_user"];

    cell.like_counter.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"likes"]];

    cell.commenter_name.text=[dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"status_timeline"];

    cell.comments.text=[dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"tgl_timeline"];


    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

    return  cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that, you are converting image url to `NSData` in main thread that is why the lag scrolling happens. You need to convert image url to `NSData` in background queue and update the UI in main queue.

That way you load each image in the background and as soon as its loaded the corresponding cell is updated on the mainThread.

The following code may help you

```
 NSURL *urlimage = [NSURL URLWithString:[dataArray objectForKey:@"pic_user"]];
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
            NSData *Dataimage = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlimage];
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
             cell.uploder_image.image =[UIImage imageWithData:Dataimage];
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try NSURLRequest also

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[dataArray objectForKey:@"pic_timeline"]];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                 completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response,
                 NSData * data, NSError * error) 
{

    if (!error) {

        cell.upload_image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your loading images using some `URL` then the best way is to load images `Asynchronously`. So I suggest you to check the below links to load images `Asynchronously`

1. [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView)
2. [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Answer (score 0):

This Happens Due to The Size of image is Big. 
1.Reuduce the Image Sizes to (below 200 kb) without Reducing The Quality in Backend
2.Download The images In Background

```
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadPhotoTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
                                                   downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your_URL"] completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                            UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];

                                                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                           downloadAllImageview.image=downloadedImage;
                                                           [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                                                           [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                                                       });

                                                   }];

    [downloadPhotoTask resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Try SDWebimage Library or download image Asynchronous

If you using SDWebimage please try this method:-

[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/olivier.poitrey/picture"]
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar-placeholder.png"]
                      options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

Answer (score 0):

The slow loading could be because of the large data objects you have put on display. You could use some cache libraries or execute the cache provided by objective-C through `NSCache` class. The other thing you could do is use the `ComponentKit` library provided by Facebook in your project.

Caching libraries:

[FastImageCache](https://github.com/path/FastImageCache)

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Timeline Libraries:

[Facebook's Component Kit](https://github.com/facebook/componentkit)